# Avoiding deeply nested Option cascades in Scala

Tags: scala, nested, scala-cats, scala-option

Say I have three database access functions `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` that can each return `Option[A]` where `A` is some model class, and the calls depend on each other.

I would like to call the functions sequentially and in each case, return an appropriate error message if the value is not found (`None`).

My current code looks like this:

```
Input is a URL: /x/:xID/y/:yID/z/:zID

foo(xID) match {
  case None => Left(s"$xID is not a valid id")
  case Some(x) =>
    bar(yID) match {
      case None => Left(s"$yID is not a valid id")
      case Some(y) =>
        baz(zID) match {
          case None => Left(s"$zID is not a valid id")
          case Some(z) => Right(process(x, y, z))
        }
    }
}
```

As can be seen, the code is badly nested.

If instead, I use a `for` comprehension, I cannot give specific error messages, because I do not know which step failed:

```
(for {
  x <- foo(xID)
  y <- bar(yID)
  z <- baz(zID)
} yield {
  Right(process(x, y, z))
}).getOrElse(Left("One of the IDs was invalid, but we do not know which one"))
```

If I use `map` and `getOrElse`, I end up with code almost as nested as the first example.

Is these some better way to structure this to avoid the nesting while allowing specific error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution (based on @Rex's solution and his comments):

```
def ifTrue[A](boolean: Boolean)(isFalse: => A): RightProjection[A, Unit.type] =
  Either.cond(boolean, Unit, isFalse).right

def none[A](option: Option[_])(isSome: => A): RightProjection[A, Unit.type] =
  Either.cond(option.isEmpty, Unit, isSome).right

def some[A, B](option: Option[A])(ifNone: => B): RightProjection[B, A] =
  option.toRight(ifNone).right
```

They do the following:

- `ifTrue` is used when a function returns a `Boolean`, with `true` being the "success" case (e.g.: `isAllowed(userId)`). It actually returns `Unit` so should be used as `_ <- ifTrue(...) { error }` in a `for` comprehension.
- `none` is used when a function returns an `Option` with `None` being the "success" case (e.g.: `findUser(email)` for creating accounts with unique email addresses). It actually returns `Unit` so should be used as `_ <- none(...) { error }` in a `for` comprehension.
- `some` is used when a function returns an `Option` with `Some()` being the "success" case (e.g.: `findUser(userId)` for a `GET /users/userId`). It returns the contents of the `Some`: `user <- some(findUser(userId)) { s"user $userId not found" }`.

They are used in a `for` comprehension:

```
for {
  x <- some(foo(xID)) { s"$xID is not a valid id" }
  y <- some(bar(yID)) { s"$yID is not a valid id" }
  z <- some(baz(zID)) { s"$zID is not a valid id" }
} yield {
  process(x, y, z)
}
```

This returns an `Either[String, X]` where the `String` is an error message and the `X` is the result of calling `process`.

Answer (score 7):

You can get your `for` loop working by using right projections.

```
def ckErr[A](id: String, f: String => Option[A]) = (f(id) match {
  case None => Left(s"$id is not a valid id")
  case Some(a) => Right(a)
}).right

for {
  x <- ckErr(xID, foo)
  y <- ckErr(yID, bar)
  z <- ckErr(zID, baz)
} yield process(x,y,z)
```

This is still a little clumsy, but it has the advantage of being part of the standard library.

Exceptions are another way to go, but they slow things down a *lot* if the failure cases are common.  I'd only use that if failure was truly exceptional.

It's also possible to use non-local returns, but it's kind of awkward for this particular setup.  I think right projections of `Either` are the way to go.  If you really like working this way but dislike putting `.right` all over the place, there are various places you can find a "right-biased Either" which will act like the right projection by default (e.g. [ScalaUtils](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.1.5/index.html#org.scalautils.Or), Scalaz, etc.).

Comment: That's almost exactly the solution I came up with after playing around with the code :-).

Comment: My converter looks like this: `def right[A, B](option: Option[A])(ifNone: B): RightProjection[B, A] = option.toRight(ifNone).right`

Comment: You probably want `ifNone: => B` so you don't have to build the failure case every time even when there isn't a failure.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an `Option` I would instead use a `Try`. That way you have the Monadic composition that you'd like mixed with the ability to retain the error.

```
def myDBAccess(..args..) =
 thingThatDoesStuff(args) match{
   case Some(x) => Success(x)
   case None => Failure(new IdError(args))
 }
```

I'm assuming in the above that you don't actually control the functions and can't refactor them to give you a non-`Option`. If you did, then simply substitute `Try`.

Comment: I filed a ticket to refactor the code to return `Either`, but have not had time to work on it. We have many cases like this one.

Comment: @Ralph Either would work too. I like `Try` because it says `Success` and `Failure`. Using `Try` doesn't mean you have to throw an exception, you can actually have a non-stack allocating exception which doesn't slow down the process.

Comment: @wheaties - It's a little dangerous to have stackless exceptions floating around since if they get thrown you have no idea where they came from.  It's better, if possible, to at least use the loan pattern when working with them, e.g. `getAStacklessException(params){ e => ??? /* Don't store e anywhere or use futures! */ }`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was answered some time back, but I wanted to give an alternative to the accepted answer.

Given that, in your example, the three `Option`s are independent, you can treat them as Applicative Functors and use `ValidatedNel` from Cats to simplify and aggregate the handling of the unhappy path.

Given the code:

```
  import cats.data.Validated.{invalidNel, valid}

  def checkOption[B, T](t : Option[T])(ifNone : => B) : ValidatedNel[B, T] = t match {
    case None => invalidNel(ifNone)
    case Some(x) => valid(x)

  def processUnwrappedData(a : Int, b : String, c : Boolean) : String = ???

  val o1 : Option[Int] = ???
  val o2 : Option[String] = ???
  val o3 : Option[Boolean] = ???
```

You can then replicate obtain what you want with:

```
//import cats.syntax.cartesian._
( 
  checkOption(o1)(s"First option is not None") |@|
  checkOption(o2)(s"Second option is not None") |@|
  checkOption(o3)(s"Third option is not None")
 ) map (processUnwrappedData)
```

This approach will allow you to aggregate failures, which was not possible in your solution (as using for-comprehensions enforces sequential evaluation). More examples and documentation can be found [here](https://softwaremill.com/applicative-functor/) and [here](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/Validated.html).

Finally this solution uses Cats `Validated` but could easily be translated to Scalaz `Validation`